# Should I declare a faux wood object to customs when entering Australia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia

Should I declare the item I'm bringing to Australia; even though it is made out of faux wood?

It is not actual wood and does not fall into the category of wooden goods as I just checked (it is actually made out of an artificial resin); however, it very **convincingly** looks like wood. I have the official UPC barcode of the item and everything, and I know it comes from the USA, so...

Should I declare it to avoid confusion or can I skip that? I will be carrying it with me along with the information of the item.

Answer (score 6):

The item is not wood: there is no need to declare it. If you're stopped and asked about it, it should be no problem to explain that it's made of resin.